# What's the difference between CCK Decimal and Float fields?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

[CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck)'s Number submodule provides two fields: decimal and float. Decimals are technically floats, so what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decimals are fixed point, not floating point. Decimal store exact numeric data values.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html